# Вынос блоков 'div' во внешний js файл

Tags: javascript, html

Для того, чтобы роботы поисковых систем индексировали только важную информацию – контент страницы и элементы навигации, я вычитал что полезно служебные блоки вынести во внешний файл, используя **JavaScript**. Расскажите, сталкивались вы с таким и как **реализовывали**, потому что я пока не могу представить.

Comment: а можно ссылку на статью, где про это пишут?

Answer (score 3):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex может это вам поможет

Comment: Спасибо, очень дельная информация, хотелось бы еще выслушать, как модно вынести блоки используя js.

Comment: если выносить, думаю, вам поможет, например, что-то наподобие этого http://handlebarsjs.com/